# Laravel 5.3 set second attribute name in custom validation rule

Tags: laravel, validation

I have the following custom validation rule...

```
Validator::extend('empty_with', function ($attribute, $value, $parameters, $validator) {
   $other = array_get($validator->getData(), $parameters[0], null);
   return ($value != '' && $other != '') ? false : true;
}, "The :attribute field is not required with the :other field.");
```

And am using it like...

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'officer' => 'sometimes|integer',
    'station' => 'empty_with:officer,|integer',
]);
```

The current error message am getting is

`The station field is not required with the`**`:other`**`field.`

Versus what I would like to have;

`The station field is not required with the officer field.`

How do I set a the second parameter 'officer' in the error message, the same way :attribute is...??

Comment: Try removing the comma (,) after `officer,`

Comment: It changes nothing, 

How can I set the second parameter name in the error message; am guessing something like `:attribute_2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to add in a custom replacer to go with your custom validation rule. See 'Defining the error message' [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/validation#using-extensions).

```
\Validator::replacer('empty_with', function ($message, $attribute, $rule, $parameters) {
    return str_replace(':other', $parameters[0], $message);
});
```

This code tells Laravel that when the `empty_with` rule fails, the message should be run through that closure before being passed back to the user. The closure performs a simple string replacement and returns the amended error message.

For the most part, each validation rule has its own replacement rules for messages since it's dependent on the specific attributes and their order. Although `:other` being replaced with the first parameter happens for a few rules, it's not automatic and is defined explicitly for each rule that uses it. It's worth looking in the `Illuminate\Validation\Concerns\ReplacesAttributes` trait to get an idea of how Laravel deals with replacement for its built-in rules.

Comment: How can I use the `replacer` in a custom validation rule class.

Comment: I'm not actually sure, I don't think it's documented. There is a `callClassBasedReplacer` method in `Illuminate\Validation\Concerns\FormatsMessages` (line 378) which looks like it might call a `replace` method on the class, but I couldn't get it to work in the couple of minutes I spent trying.